# Web API: How to get a route parameter when controller action does not have corresponding argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

We build multi-tenancy application with Web API 2. We want to embed tenant info into the URL so that every request can get it. E.g. http://localhost/tenant1/api/test. 
We added an action filter that should extract tenant from the request. However, it works only when controller action method signature has corresponding parameter.

Here is the code:

```
public class ValidationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // works only if controller action has that argument
        var tenant = actionContext.ActionArguments["tenant"]; 

        Console.Out.WriteLine("tenant = {0}", tenant);
        return base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

It works well when controller is like that:

```
[RoutePrefix("{tenant}")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/test")]
    public string Get(string tenant) // we don't need it here
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

The `tenant` is going to be used only in action filter, so adding it to each and every controller method seems to be a silly thing. We want that controller to be:

```
 public string Get() {...}
```

Is there any way to obtain that value in action filter when controller action does not have a corresponding argument?

Answer (score 2):

Found answer just after posting the question :)

```
  actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["tenant"]
```

just works even when action does not have that argument.