# How to get argument in action filter when the controller action has no corresponding argument?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, query-string, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 6 based web application. To avoid writing a lot of redundant code in my controllers, I implemented a class `BaseController` which all of my controllers inherit from. In that class, I overrided the `OnActionExecutionAsync` method to run the code which would otherwise be redundant in every controller. In this code, I need to access two arguments which I would otherwise have to pass to each controller action via its arguments like this:
`public async Task<ActionResult> ExampleAction([FromQuery(Name = "argument1")] Guid? argument1, [FromQuery(Name = "argument2")] Guid? argument2)`

As long as I keep those arguments in every action, I can easily access them in the `OnActionExecutionAsync` method. However, I do not want to do it like this because it would require me to add the arguments to every single controller action while I do not even need them there. Now I have the problem that when I remove the arguments from the controller action, I can no longer access them via `context.ActionArguments` in the `OnActionExecutionAsync` method.

Is there any way how I can still access the arguments in this situation? I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060101/web-api-how-to-get-a-route-parameter-when-controller-action-does-not-have-corre) question on SO which is very similar but the suggested solution to use `actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["tenant"]` does not work in my case. There simply is no `ControllerContext` in ASP.NET Core 6 and `context.RouteData.Values` does not seem to contain the arguments I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the query-string values using `HttpContext.Request.Query`. Here's an example:

```cs
var tenantValues = context.HttpContext.Request.Query["tenant"];
```

The type of `tenantValues` here is `StringValues`, which represents one or more values. If you know there's only going to be one value provided, you can treat it as a collection and use `[0]` or `First()`, for example, or just case it as `string`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpContext` property of [`ActionContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actioncontext.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0) (which is ancestor of [`ActionExecutingContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionexecutingcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0)) to access request query string values:

```cs
public override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext actionContext, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    StringValues values = actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["tenant"];
}
```